# What happens to the rest of the League of Assassins?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In the Arrow episode "Sins of the Father", Nyssa tells Oliver, Malcom and Laura she has disbanded the League of Assassins. That sounds all well and good, but now we have a lot of trained killers with no job, no purpose, and likely no home. Two former assassins were with Nyssa when she melted the ring, it seems unlikely she had all but those two commit the LoA's equivalent to seppuku.

Where are they likely to go? I keep thinking of IRL when so many agents of the defunct KGB offered their skills to the mob, will something similar happen here?

Comment: Might be worth noting which show or specifically which timeline you're referring to. Legends of Tomorrow is changing timelines quite often, as as such what is 'canon' now easily stops being so tomorrow. One example would be Arrow not losing an arm and all.

Comment: Arrow/Oliver never lost an arm, he took off Malcolm Merlyn's hand.

Comment: in Legends of Tomorrow he does. Or rather, he's shown in 2046 as having been cut an arm by Deathstroke. Or rather, Deathstroke Jr. Which IS cannon. However, it's only canon as long as the Legends doesn't mess with the timeline again

Comment: @Oak It's canon that there was one timeline in which Oliver lost his arm at some point between 2016 and 2046, which is about as vague as canon gets. The whole point of the episode was that that particular timeline won't - or at least might not - end up happening if Sara and Ray return to Star City in 2016. Ultimately I think the Legends timeline/canon should be consideted separate from the Arrow/Flash canon, because anything we see after 2016 is going to get wiped out.

Comment: Which is exactly what I mean, Legends is and will always be canon on Arrow/Flash. However, events in Legends may be 'no longer events', at least for those who are not the lengends due to the timeline changing. Since three shows messing with the same canon are currently active, it should be specified exactly in what season/episode (or as close as possible) the question is referring to, since it can be spoiler prone. Eg: I can say in current canon Oliver loses an arm ... but when/if it's set in stone is a whole different matter